# Geo distance search with realm database android

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, location, realm

I want to get a listed restaurant have lat/long are 5 kilometers from my current location in realm database as this library [[1](https://github.com/mhergon/RealmGeoQueries)]

Have the best way for me to do something like that in android.

Comment: There's no easy way to that on Realm Java right now, but all the logic of the Swift version is contained in a single file so it should not too hard to port the same logic to Android.

Comment: Thanks @Emanuelez I will try.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to achieve this?